# How manipulate expander header from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, expander

I have this code in XAML:

```
  <Expander BorderBrush="DarkGray" Background="White" SourceUpdated="Expander_SourceUpdated" GotFocus="Expander_GotFocus">
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="Grupo " VerticalAlignment ="Center"/>
                                                        <TextBlock x:Name="Tblockgrupo" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment ="Center" GotFocus="TextBlock_GotFocus" />
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" VerticalAlignment ="Center"/>
                                                        <TextBlock Text=" Variable(s)" VerticalAlignment ="Center"/>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Expander>
```

My question is how capture the text of the TextBlock with name: Tblockgroup, from codebehind (c#) when the expander has focus.

Comment: What do you want to do with the property value?

Comment: Because I need that especific value to another operation in code behind, this expander is include in datagrid from the class GroupItem

Comment: what's "another operation"? please be specific. If you need a value which is databound from a Data item, then read the Data, not the UI.

Comment: What do you mean by 'capture the text ... expander has focus'? Your TextBlock is named and you can easily access its Tblockgrupo.Text property from code-behind on GotFocus. So what is the 'to capture'? Or do you mean that the expander does not get the focus correctly? What is the problem? What is the desired behaviour? And what is the actual?

Comment: Its no only one expander, are multiple expander

Comment: @user3795085 WHAT do you need to do with the property?

Comment: The property is only idea, I need the value in that TextBlock

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

object result = Prueba.FindName("name");
            if (result is TextBlock)
            {
                // Following executed if Text element was found.
                TextBlock resultconvert = result as TextBlock;
                MessageBox.Show(resultconvert.Text);
            }